# StackOverflow.com not loading properly

Tags: support, stack-overflow

**Fixed:**
I did alot of troubleshooting and testing diffrent solutions(see rest of the post and comments).

**I got it working after doing the following steps:**

- **I ran "ipconfig /renew" in commandline.**
- **Deactivated and reactivated my network connection/network card.**
- **Hard-refreshed(ctrl+r) again.**

---

I try to get into StackOverflow.com, but all I get is text and links. Nothing is styled/formatted, and the text has no structure.

meta.stackoverflow.com works like normal. All other webpages works normal.

Here's an example of StackOverflow.com:
[image]

**Edits**

Tried:

- Firefox, Chrome and Opera. Same results in all browsers.
- Hard-refresh: Ctrl-F5 and ctrl+shift+r
- Clearing my cache

Still nothing. Seems like a CDN problem.

Other information:

- Windows 8
- Chrome
- 50mb bandwidth

Edit2

```
Einar>tracert cdn.sstatic.net

Tracing route to sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net [2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f73a]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2a00:c440:20:12c2::1
  2     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  2a00:c440:5:1::1
  3    <1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  2a02:2690:0:f::11
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

Einar>
```

Comment: Does seem like a CDN problem. But the solutions/troubleshooting posted in that post are too complicated for me. I don't understand them.

Comment: Try loading http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=dafcffdb6e85 directly, see what you get.

Comment: It tries loading cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=dafcffdb6e85, but returns "This webpage is not available".

Comment: Are you behind a filtering proxy? Do you have any domain-filtering software? Anything like that?

Comment: Also: what happens if you `tracert cdn.sstatic.net` ? or if you `ping cdn.sstatic.net` ?

Comment: No filtering proxy that I know of. Is there any way of checking? I haven't installed any network-related software.

Comment: Where do I run tracert cdn.sstatic.net? In commandline?

Comment: @Einar yes, it is a command-line tool; it will usually take about 30 seconds and about 5-15 "hops" to get there

Comment: Hmmm... looks like most likely a CDN/DNS/routing problem - it probably is unrelated to your machine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KDnlT.png

Comment: Tracert took about 6 mins, 30 hops, most got request timed out. See edits in main post for full picture.

Comment: Ohh, okay. So if it's a CDN/DNS/routing problem, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: This looks like an issue with your ISP. Nothing you can do except yell at them and hope the technical support person you are yelling at has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow style sheet isn't downloading/loading. That is why you still see all the basic stuff like text.

Sometimes this can be solved by pressing ctrl+F5.

It is normally caused by a **slow internet connection**

Comment: I've tried ctrl-F5/hard-refresh, still nothing. Also tried to clear my cache.

Comment: Clearing cache did not resolve this, @Einar?

Comment: @TinyTim No, unfortunatly not.

Comment: How fast is your internet connection? It can sometimes time out and leave the style sheet. Are the style sheets loading fine on other websites?